# Apache Airflow S3ListOperator not listing files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I am trying to use the `airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3_list` **S3ListOperator** to list files in an S3 bucket in my AWS account with the DAG operator below:

```
list_bucket = S3ListOperator(
    task_id = 'list_files_in_bucket',
    bucket = '<MY_BUCKET>',
    aws_conn_id = 's3_default'
)
```

I have configured my `Extra` Connection details in the form of: `{"aws_access_key_id": "<MY_ACCESS_KEY>", "aws_secret_access_key": "<MY_SECRET_KEY>"}`

When I run my Airflow job, it *appears* it is executing fine & my task status is **Success**.  Here is the Log output:

```
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,009] {base_aws.py:368} INFO - Airflow Connection: aws_conn_id=s3_default
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,013] {base_aws.py:170} INFO - Credentials retrieved from extra_config
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,013] {base_aws.py:84} INFO - Creating session with aws_access_key_id=<MY_ACCESS_KEY> region_name=None
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,027] {base_aws.py:157} INFO - role_arn is None
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,661] {taskinstance.py:1185} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=two_step, task_id=list_files_in_bucket, execution_date=20210427T184422, start_date=20210427T184439, end_date=20210427T184450
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,676] {taskinstance.py:1246} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2021-04-27 11:44:50,700] {local_task_job.py:146} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Is there anything I can do to print the files in my bucket to Logs?
TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is enough and you don't need to use print function. Just check the corresponding log, then go to xcom, and the return list is there.

```
list_bucket = S3ListOperator(
        task_id='list_files_in_bucket',
        bucket='ob-air-pre',
        prefix='data/',
        delimiter='/',
        aws_conn_id='aws'
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The result from executing `S3ListOperator` is an XCom object that is stored in the Airflow database after the task instance has completed.

You need to declare another operator to feed in the results from the `S3ListOperator` and print them out.

For example in Airflow 2.0.0 and up you can use [TaskFlow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/taskflow.html):

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils import timezone

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my-workflow',
    start_date=timezone.parse('2021-01-14 21:00')
)

@dag.task(task_id="print_objects")
def print_objects(objects):
    print(objects)


list_bucket = S3ListOperator(
    task_id='list_files_in_bucket',
    bucket='<MY_BUCKET>',
    aws_conn_id='s3_default',
    dag=dag
)


print_objects(list_bucket.output)
```

In older versions,

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils import timezone

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my-workflow',
    start_date=timezone.parse('2021-01-14 21:00')
)
def print_objects(objects):
    print(objects)


list_bucket = S3ListOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='list_files_in_bucket',
    bucket='<MY_BUCKET>',
    aws_conn_id='s3_default',
)

print_objects_in_bucket = PythonOperator(
     dag=dag,
     task_id='print_objects_in_bucket',
     python_callable=print_objects,
     op_args=("{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='list_files_in_bucket')}}",)
)

list_bucket >> print_objects_in_bucket
```

Comment: Hi @Oluwafemi Sule , I have the same issue, I am using V 2.0.2. Trying your first solution, but getting erro. Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dag-test/MySqltoS3.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dag-test/MySqltoS3.py", line 19, in <module>
    @dag.task(task_id='print_objects_in_bucket')
NameError: name 'dag' is not defined

Comment: Hey @MaryamPashmi, the `dag` object has to be initialized from the `DAG` class. For example, `dag = DAG(id='name-of-your-workflow', start_date='date-time-object-for-when-you-want-to-start-running-dag-from', schedule='period-of-interval-to-run-the-workflow')`

Comment: yes of course i have that. I suggest if you can use a complete code , which you have tried and it's working. this will be very helpful for everyone. The code you wrote is not complete and the ones are new to airflow can't follow it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code sample has been updated to be runnable.

Comment: Thanks, I think you should remove this at the end of the first block, print_objects(list_bucket.output) , and add tasks sequence instead.